# Compare Two Files on android and php server

Tags: android, file, upload, compare, checksum

I am developing an application where I have to record audio files and upload on the server.

There is scenario where internet could be down and file is only half uploaded.

How do I compare that file with one available on the android file system so that I re-upload the file if it is not uploaded successfully ?

Comment: You can benefit of HTTP for this. if you have not finished the upload, you will have an error status or timeout

Answer (score 0):

Well you can compare checksum with some hash function like `MD5` or `SHA1`

For MD5

Assuming you use `Java` for Android function will be like this

```
 public static String checkSum(String path){
    String checksum = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int numOfBytesRead;
        while( (numOfBytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) &gt; 0){
            md.update(buffer, 0, numOfBytesRead);
        }
        byte[] hash = md.digest();
        checksum = new BigInteger(1, hash).toString(16);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
    }

   return checksum;
}
```

For `PHP` its much easier, you can just use `md5_file` function

```
$md5 = md5_file($filepath);
```